# Translate SQL to Doctrine DQL

Tags: sql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

Can anyone help me translate this SQL into Doctrine 2 DQL

From what I understand :

> Doctrine does NOT support sub-queries in the FROM clause, despite what the docs say

But there must be a way...

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT m.*,qf, y.name as annee 
  FROM pbs_members m
  LEFT JOIN pbs_qf qf ON m.id = qf.member_id
  LEFT JOIN pbs_years y ON qf.year_id=y.id
  ORDER BY y.name DESC
) AS m_temp
GROUP BY id
```

**Edit:**

I have 3 tables :

```
pbs_members (id, member_type_id, uid, address, birth_date, email)
pbs_qf (id, member_id, year_id, qf)
pbs_years (id, name)
```

What I want : All users with their QF for the curreny year, and if no QF is defined for the current year, decrement the year until you find a QF, If no QF is found, return null/no QF found

Comment: Why is the outer select required?

Comment: So that I can GROUP BY after an ORDER BY

Comment: You don't need to do that... the `order by` will apply after the `group by`.  You're working too hard, as @biziclop alludes to